# Calling javascript function with parameters from blade

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, laravel-blade

I browsed through a bunch of similar sounding questions but none of them applies to my issue. I want to pass a parameter (obtained by a `foreach`) to a javascript function (in the same file as my view) to feed several Select2 dropdowns in a datatable in my blade view. The issue seems to be that I can't pass the php variable `$process->id` to the javascript function.

From my blade view:

```
@foreach($processes as $process)                        
<tr>
  <td>{{ $process->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $process->title }}</td>
  <td>{{ $process->client }}</td>
  <td>
    <script> getDisponents($process->id); </script> //not working ofc.
    <select class="mySelect" name="state"></select> 
  </td>        
(...)
@push('js')
<script>
function getDisponents(process_id){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/matpro/public/getUsersPerProcess', //works.
    type: "get",
    data: {
      processId:process_id,
      //processId:'5', //works for manually given ids.
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('.mySelect').select2({
        data: response,
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus + " : " + jqXHR.status + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need blade to output the `$process_id` into the html script tag .... `getDisponents('{{ $process->id }}');`

Comment: How do I exactly put this? `<script> getDisponents('{{$process->id}}'); </script>` is not working.

Comment: *"not working"* doesn't tell us anything about errors thrown or what the actual generated source produces. Check browser dev tools console for errors

Comment: The error is an "uncaught syntax error" which does not help either.

Comment: So what does it look like in the generated source that gets sent to browser?

Comment: `<script> var processId = P000032        getDisponents(processId);</script>` like this but I think the call of `getDisponents();` does not work at all. I tried calling it without parameters and it does not work either.

Comment: Missing quotes in javascript around that string. There's a far simpler way to to this by using data attributes and looping over all the `.mySelect` with a javascript loop and get the id value from each data attribute

Comment: No, I mean `<script>getDisponents();</script>` does not call the function. I set `processId:'P000018'` in the function, removed the parameter and it's not being called. Could you give an example for your simpler way?

Comment: `$('.mySelect').each(function(){ var processId = $(this).data('id'); /* do ajax*/})` then in html `<select class="mySelect" data-id="{{$process->id}}"...`

Comment: Do I get this right that `$('.mySelect')` is called each time `data-id="{{$process->id}}"` is called from the `foreach`? And does `$('.mySelect')` get the `$process->id` each time this way?

Comment: No ... there would be one javascript  call of `$('.mySelect').each(function(){..` ` and within that javascript loop `this` is the current `mySelect` instance. Doing it that way keeps your php code separate from your javascript code (*"separation of concerns"*)

Comment: I get the idea but I need one different `$('.mySelect')` for each `$process`, because the contents of the dropdown lists depend on the `$process-id` (actually the ajax call). In your approach I don't see how all these `$('.mySelect')` calls get the `$process`. But maybe that's just me and you might provide an answer with code based non mine?

Comment: Inside the loop the processId is unique for each instance as it is taken from the data attribute of that instance... `var process_id = $(this).data('id')` and that gets passed to the ajax data

Comment: Hm, okay, I think I got it. Will try that... and let you know.

Comment: Will help you get around another problem also since in your success you are filling them all with same data ... data of last request processed

Comment: Sorry, I am totally lost. Could you please provide an answer with your simpler way, based in my code? This would help a lot and I can see what your approach is, because it looks promising simplifiing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is separate your javascript from the php and use data attributes on the elements themselves which can be easily retrieved using javascript.

Blade:

```
<select class="mySelect" data-id="{{$process->id}}" name="state"></select>
```

Then in JS use a loop to go through each instance and get it's id to pass to ajax and to be able to populate the correct element with the appropriate response:

```
var processUrl = 'http://localhost/matpro/public/getUsersPerProcess';

$('.mySelect').each(function(){ 
   // `this` is current instance of the collection
   var $sel = $(this), process_id = $sel.data('id');// from attribute

   $.get(processUrl , {processId:process_id}).then(function(response){
         // only pass data to current instance of select
         $sel.select2({data: response});
   }).catch(function(err){ 
         console.log('Ooops, something went wrong')
   });    
});
```

With all this being said, I don't really understand why you don't populate each one server side

Comment: Me neither, because I am new to this blade ajax stuff and therefore I most likely don't pick the best solution upfront. I thank you for your code example but i still don't understand where to put the ajax call.

Comment: `$.get` is shorthand for `$.ajax` when type is get

Comment: Now I see and it's working. But there is one weird thing: I added `$sel.val($('.mySelect option:eq(1)').val()).trigger('change');` to have the first entry selected in the dropdowns and this is working for some dropdowns, for some not. When I reload the page, it is working for randomly other dropdowns, it's not deterministic. Any idea?

Comment: Should use the `select2` plugin API  to change the value probably. Ooooh and don't use `$('.mySelect` either. Use $sel.find('option:eq(1)')` for that specific instace

Comment: Yes I already tried `$sel.select2.val($('.mySelect option:eq(1)').val()).trigger('change');` but this not working at all.

Comment: See my last comment update about using `$sel` otherwise you get value of first one in page

Comment: Hm, no, `$sel.find('option:eq(1)').val()).trigger('change');` not showing anyting.

Comment: Again should be doing it through select2 if you have activated it already

Comment: `$sel.select2.find('option:eq(1)').val().trigger('change');` is not bringing up any selection either but maybe it's a side effect, because some dropdowns have no elements (yet).

Comment: That syntax is most likely not correct for using the plugin and likely throws errors in your browser dev tools console. Also if some are not populated that adds a whole different level of complexity to it

Comment: You are totally right, there are several `$sel.find(...).val() is undefined` and `jQuery.Deferred exception: response is not defined` in the console. In future there won't be any empty dropdowns and the syntax works fine in dropdowns on other views of the project. So thanks a lot, I really learned something here!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
     <script> 
    var processId = <?php echo $process->id ?>
getDisponents(processId)
    function getDisponents(process_id){ $.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost/matpro/public/getUsersPerProcess', //works. type: "get", data: { processId:process_id, }, success: function(response) { $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({ data: fData, }); }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + " : " + jqXHR.status + " : " + errorThrown); } }); } </script>
```

Comment: Can't do that due to the loop